# How to search facebook & Linkedin Users by using name or Phonenumber

Tags: javascript, angular, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework

Hi i am having a requirement where i have to search the Facebook users by using the name or phone number or email id and For LinkedIn also same. I checked the Graphic for Facebook but i unable to find such api for that and is there any other work around? and this is for angular & javascript & ionic domains.

here how can i search the user by using the mobile number/email id/name and suppose if user logs in how can get the places they visited .

below is the response im getting from facebook

```
{
  "id": "12345678", 
  "birthday": "1/1/1950", 
  "first_name": "Chris", 
  "gender": "male", 
  "last_name": "Colm", 
  "link": "http://www.facebook.com/12345678", 
  "location": {
    "id": "110843418940484", 
    "name": "Seattle, Washington"
  }, 
  "locale": "en_US", 
  "name": "Chris Colm", 
  "timezone": -8, 
  "updated_time": "2010-01-01T16:40:43+0000", 
  "verified": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get ANY data of users who did not authorize your App on Facebook. User search got removed recently so it is not even possible to search by name anymore: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4